# Validate form input with regex (no jquery)

Tags: solspace-freeform

I'm getting a lot of spam om my websites where I have a couple of email/contact forms.

The forms are all validated/submitted inline with jQuery/ajax.

However, spam bots skip javascript so I want to validate the form natively too.

I don't want to use a (hidden) CAPTCHA.

EE/CI can validate emails and numbers etc. But I have a phone number field for example and I don't want to force users to use a specific pattern 000-000-000 etc.
I just want to allow only 0-9 spaces and dashes and ().
At the moment spam bots put anything there.

Also, I have a name field which spam bots use to put email addresses in. So I would like to **disallow** the @ sign and other symbols that no one uses in their name.

Also I don't want to even accept html tags or common spam strings like "

How would I do this without javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't have such validations via the freeform tags. You will need to develop an extension with the hook `freeform_module_validate_begin`. Within the hooked function you can validate the user inputs and prepare the $error array.

You can take a reference from here: http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/extension_hooks/#freeform_module_validate_begin

Comment: Thanks! I think this is the way to go.
It's a shame though, because I could use these rules if there were a regex option or just some other options: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference
To me it seems such a basic functionality...

Answer (score 0):

Freeform 4 allows specifying different types of text inputs, including numbers, when creating text fields: http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/default_fieldtypes/#text_field_content_type

Input failing the requirements will be validated negative.

Comment: Thanks, however, a phone number is not just a number so this won't work.